# Sqlalchemy multiple insert fails with percentage symbol (%) in column name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use sqlalchemy (version 1.0.11) to perform a multi-insert on a table that has columns with percentage symbols in the column names. Rows can be inserted one at a time without a problem, but when the performing a multi-insert with `con.execute()` a `OperationalError` exception is raised.

The code below reproduces the problem. Two tables are created, one with percentage names in columns, the other without.

1. The multi-insert on the table with % in the column names fails.
2. Inserting rows one by one in the table with the % in column names works.
3. Multi-insert on the table without % in column names works.

```py
    from sqlalchemy import *
    
    USER = 'root'
    PASSWORD = ''
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    DBNAME = 'test'
    
    connect_str = "mysql://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}/{DBNAME}".format(
        USER = USER,
        PASSWORD = PASSWORD,
        HOST = HOST,
        DBNAME = DBNAME
    )
    
    engine = create_engine(connect_str, echo = False)
    
    metadata = MetaData()
    
    table_with_percent = Table('table_with_percent', metadata,
         Column('A%', Integer),
         Column('B%', Integer)
    )
    
    table_no_percent = Table('table_no_percent', metadata,
         Column('A', Integer),
         Column('B', Integer)
    )
    
    metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst = True)
    
    #####################################
    # Create rows to be inserted
    
    rows = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
    table_with_percent_rows = [dict(zip(table_with_percent.c.keys(), row)) for row in rows]
    table_no_percent_rows = [dict(zip(table_no_percent.c.keys(), row)) for row in rows]
```

## Try the inserts

```
con = engine.connect()
```

**THIS FAILS!** Mutli insert on table with percentage symbol in column names.

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'A%%' in 'field list'") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO table_with_percent (`A%%`, `B%%`) VALUES (%s, %s)'] [parameters: ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))]
    con.execute(table_with_percent.insert(), table_with_percent_rows)
```

But the rows can be inserted one by one:

```
for row in table_with_percent_rows:
    con.execute(table_with_percent.insert(), row)
```

**This works!** Multi insert on table with no percent in columns

```
con.execute(table_no_percent.insert(), table_no_percent_rows)
con.close()
```

---

**UPDATE:** I opened [this](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3702) issue with the sqlalchemy issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING** Using fancy characters (any except `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`) in the column/table name is one of the guaranteed methods to shot yourself in the foot.

**TL;DR** It seems to be a bug in SQLAlchemy. It incorrectly escapes columns with `%` in name. You can go to the [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues) and report a bug (if it's not reported yet).

You want to put a breakpoint in the `do_execute()` method of `sqlalchemy.engine.default.DefaultDialect`. It is the place, where your query and parameters are passed from SA to the database driver. In your case SQL looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_with_percent (`A%%`, `B%%`) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

Yes, SQLAlchemy added second `%` to the column names. Which obviously makes columns invalid. You're better ask on the issue tracker why it happens.

With inserting of a single row it works, because of a lucky coincidence. `"%s" % ("value",)` syntax is used to format parameters into query. And in the format string `%%` is the way to escape `%` character, so after formatting query returns to the correct form:

```
INSERT INTO table_with_percent (`A%`, `B%`) VALUES (1, 2)
```

In case of inserting multiple rows lucky coincidence doesn't happen, since formatting of the params is done differently. And you end up with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table_with_percent (`A%%`, `B%%`) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
```

Which obviously fails.

PS You can use following syntax to get it working:

```
con.execute(table_with_percent.insert().values(table_with_percent_rows))
```